# Sencha ExtJS - Display combo picker always on top of the control

Tags: extjs

So I have this specific combo that I need to display its picker always on top (just as it behaves when it is too near to the bottom of the page). As shown here:

[image]

I tried with the pickerAlign config but I wasn't able to put it on top of my control. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, this will do:

```
pickerAlign : 'b-t'
```

Anyway, it displays the same amount of items it would as if there was the same space on top of it that the amount beneath it.